# How to search and update records with EF

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to find records that contain a text string in a field/property and then replace the text string with a new text string and then save the update record.

I am not sure way the code belowis not working. I have put break points and name variable does have the replaced text but when I look at the record in the database, the field still have the original value.

```
var vendors = db.Vendor.Where(c=> c.Name.Contains("Corp."));
foreach( var vendor in vendors)
{
    var name = vendor.Name.Replace("Corp.", "Corporation");
    vendor.Name = name;

}
db.SaveChanges();
```

**Update**
I ended up using this hack for now.

```
var vendors = db.Vendor.Where(c=> c.Name.Contains("Corp."));
foreach( var vendor in vendors)
{
    var v = db.Vendor.Find(vendor.ID);
    var name = vendor.Name.Replace("Corp.", "Corporation");
    v.Name = name;        
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot mark your entity's state as modified, try the following code

```
var vendors = db.Vendor.Where(c=> c.Name.Contains("Corp."));
foreach(var vendor in vendors)
{
    var name = vendor.Name.Replace("Corp.", "Corporation");
    vendor.Name = name;
    db.Entry(vendor).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```